# How to pull out cells out of a table to create a new table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

How can I pull out cells (**Names**) and their corresponding cells (**Ages**) out of a table to create a new one?

I have the column of names and ages below:

[image]

I'd like to pull out the following:

[image]

So that my final column will be as it is below in Names_final and Ages_final

[image]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `FILTER` function?

Comment: @BigBen yeah it does

Comment: Hi Mayukh, it was my mistake in the original because I didn't ask for the final table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FILTER` and `COUNTIFS`:

```
=FILTER(A2:B9,COUNTIFS(D2:D4,A2:A9)=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Exclude Matches in Two Columns

- The star of the show is the `FILTER` function.
- Using `COUNTIFS`, you could do:

```
=FILTER(A2:B12,COUNTIFS(D2:D4,A2:A12,E2:E4,B2:B12)=0,"")
```

- Using a double `XMATCH`, you could do:

```
=FILTER(A2:B12,NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A12,D2:D4)*XMATCH(B2:B12,E2:E4))),"")
```

[image]

- To make it more flexible for the `COUNTIFS` version, you could do:

```
=LET(md,A2:B12,mnc,1,mac,2,ed,D2:E4,enc,1,eac,2,
    mn,INDEX(md,,mnc),ma,INDEX(md,,mac),
    en,INDEX(ed,,enc),ea,INDEX(ed,,eac),
    f,COUNTIFS(en,mn,ea,ma)=0,
FILTER(md,f,""))
```

with the following variable naming logic:

```
m - match
e - exclusion
d - data
n - name
a - age
c - column
f - filter
```

- The same for the `XMATCH` version requires only a different filter:

```
    f,NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(mn,en)*XMATCH(ma,ea))),
```